# javafx: binding properties together and displaying them in tableview

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following class which contains price, volume properties and any changes in these two properties should lead to an update in the transaction fee.

```
public class GroceryCounter {


    private DoubleProperty volume;
    private DoubleProperty price;
    private DoubleBinding transactionFee;

    public double getVolume(){
        return this.volume.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty volumeProperty(){
        return this.volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(double volume){
        this.volume.set(volume);
    }


    public double getPrice(){
        return this.price.get();
    }   

    public DoubleProperty priceProperty(){
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public double getTransactionFee(){
            this.transactionFee = this.price.multiply(this.volume).multiply(0.0025);
            return this.transactionFee.getValue();
    }

    public DoubleBinding transactionFeeProperty(){
        return this.transactionFee;
    }
}
```

This is the code I use in my `Controller` class.

```
public TableColumn<Trade, Double> transactionFeeColumn;
......

 // in the initialize method
 transactionFeeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().transactionFeeProperty());
```

**Problem**:

1. I am failing to display the transaction fee on the table column with the following message:

   Type mismatch: cannot convert from DoubleBinding to ObservableValue

I feel very unsafe about the code above, as I feel that I should be using `getTransactionFee()` instead of `transactionFeeProperty()` for displaying results in tableColumn.

2. Am I correctly binding the price property and volume property properly to `transactionFee` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change :

```
public TableColumn<Trade, Double> transactionFeeColumn;
```

to:

```
public TableColumn<GroceryCounter, Number> transactionFeeColumn;
```

Why? because:
The `DoubleBinding` class implements `ObservableValue<Number>` interface.

Your model class should look like the following:

```
    public class GroceryCounter  {

    private final DoubleProperty volume = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private final DoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private  final DoubleBinding transactionFee;

    public GroceryCounter () {
        this.transactionFee = this.price.multiply(this.volume).multiply(0.0025);
    }



    public double getVolume() {
        return this.volume.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty volumeProperty() {
        return this.volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(double volume) {
        this.volume.set(volume);
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public double getTransactionFee() {

            return this.transactionFee.getValue();
    }

    public DoubleBinding transactionFeeProperty() {
        return this.transactionFee;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Here is an example:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TableColumn<GroceryCounter, Number> TransCol = new TableColumn("transactionFee");
        TransCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().transactionFeeProperty());
        TableColumn<GroceryCounter, Number> priceCol = new TableColumn("price");
        priceCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty());
        TableColumn<GroceryCounter, Number> volumeCol = new TableColumn("volume");
        volumeCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().volumeProperty());
        GroceryCounter item = new GroceryCounter();
        item.setPrice(10);
        item.setVolume(10);
        TableView<GroceryCounter> table = new TableView();
        table.getColumns().addAll(volumeCol, priceCol, TransCol);
        table.getItems().add(item);
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().add(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how could you tie the `getTransactionFee()` instance method to the TableColumn in Controller?